# How do I keep a tkinter GUI responsive when running a subprocess for its stdout?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a GUI for my python script with Tkinter. I want I fairly simple just window where you can type the IP you want to ping and a button to execute the command. Here is my script:

```
import os
address = input("Enter Ip Here:")
os.system(f"ping {address} -t -l 65500")
```

So basically what I want is to be able to type the {address} in a small window and then press a button below to execute this but I can't figure out how to do this. (I have already tried the script and it works in the cmd prompt. I just want a GUI for it. Help would be appreciated!

I also made a separate script which opens a window with Tkinter and it has an exit button to close the window:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import ttk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Ping Of Death')

# exit button
exit_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Execute',
    command=lambda: root.quit()
)

exit_button.pack(
    ipadx=5,
    ipady=5,
    expand=True
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Here's a Tkinter tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/

Comment: Hello! Can you show us how far you've gotten until now? Perhaps you've already managed to open a window with tkinter, or open a window with a text field, or a window with a text field and a button - that way, we know which next step you would like help with.

Comment: So ive looked around quite a bit and managed to make a separate script wich opens a window with an exit button. I will edit the post and put it there

Comment: You need to look at creating an `Entry` as well as a function that uses the  `get` method on said `Entry`.  Then you can use your function as the `command` in your `Button`. Look at [this tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-entry/).  Just note that it uses python 3 `tkinter` and not 2 `Tkinter`  like you are using.

Comment: remember: event handlers must return within a fraction of a second, or else that would *block the event loop, causing the program to become unresponsive* -- that is why I've had to downvote both answers below. both answers exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Used ip address or hostname.

```
import functools
import os
import tkinter as tk
from concurrent import futures

 
thread_pool_executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
 

 
def tk_after(target):
 
    @functools.wraps(target)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args = (self,) + args
        self.after(0, target, *args, **kwargs)
 
    return wrapper
 
 
def submit_to_pool_executor(executor):
 
    def decorator(target):
 
        @functools.wraps(target)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return executor.submit(target, *args, **kwargs)
 
        return wrapper
 
    return decorator

 
 
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.master.geometry('500x350')
        self.master.title("Get output inside GUI")
        self.entry = tk.StringVar()
        label = tk.Label(
            self.master, text="Enter target IP or host as required.")
        label.pack()
        entry = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.entry)
        entry.insert(-1, "8.8.8.8")
        entry.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(
            self.master, text="Ping Test", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(self.master)
        self.text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.text.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        
 
    @tk_after
    def button_state(self, enabled=True):
        state = tk.NORMAL
        if not enabled:
            state = tk.DISABLED
        self.button.config(state=state)

         
    @tk_after
    def clear_text(self):
        self.text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        
 
    @tk_after
    def insert_text(self, text):
        self.text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.text.insert(tk.END, text)
        self.text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        
 
    def on_button(self):
        self.ping()
        
 
    @submit_to_pool_executor(thread_pool_executor)
    def ping(self):
        self.button_state(False)
        self.clear_text()
        self.insert_text(f'Starting ping request')
 
        result = os.popen(f"ping {self.entry.get()} -n 2")
        for line in result:
            self.insert_text(line)
 
        self.insert_text(f'ping request finished')
        self.button_state(True)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this you need to add an `Entry` to your window and execute your ping with `address` being set to the value of the entry once your button is pressed. Here is a simple example on how this could work:

```
import tkinter as tk


def ping(address):
    import os
    os.system(f"ping {address} -t -l 65500")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Ping Of Death')

ip_input_label = tk.Label(root, text="IP: ")
ip_input_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

ip_input = tk.Entry(root)
ip_input.grid(row=0, column=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Ping", command=lambda: ping(ip_input.get()))
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the `ping` command, in your code, is being executed in an **event handler**. since it takes more than a fraction of a second, this will **block the event loop, causing the program to become unresponsive**.